# How do I use GROUP BY to show multiple objects rather than just one for each grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `users` table of names and timezones. I want to show all the names for each timezone. When I try:

```
SELECT timezone, name FROM users GROUP BY timezone;
```

It only gives me one name for each timezone. I want a list of all the names for each timezone. How would I construct this type of query?

Comment: then don't use a `group by`. `order by timezone` instead. `group` COLLAPSES any matching records into a single representative record.

Comment: `Select timezone, name From users Order By timezone, name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting all the names you may use `group_concat` but make sure `group_concat_max_len` is set properly
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
select
timezone,
group_concat(name) as names  
FROM users GROUP BY timezone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQLs `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, which will give you a comma separated list of all the names. Try this:

```
SELECT timezone, GROUP_CONCAT(name)
FROM users
GROUP BY timezone;
```

Here is a [reference](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) on the function.